# using correct Scala type to lower memory footprint

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a really big dataset which I process locally using Spark.

The dataset contains of Tuple with relations between two users where the usernames are String and the relation is Double:

```
(("Bob", "John"), 0.5)
```

The dataset takes too much memory and I get `Java heap space` errors and the program crashes.

My plan is to lower the footprint of the dataset by using different representation of the memory.
My initial idea was to change the String usernames to their hash value but apparently Scala collections accept only classes so I have to use `Integer` for this which didn't help. as [referenced here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html) Int/Integer are objects and of course have overhead to the data.

Since collections can't be used with primitives I found the [TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#TYPE) data type which as far as I understand also an Object.

My question is really 2 questions:

1. Is there really no good way to use primitives in collections?
2. Are there any other hacks one can apply where dealing with such giant tables of the type I specified earlier?

Comment: Are you using RDDs or Datasets? Datasets has optimized in-memory columnar format, so it can save a lot of memory

Comment: Value classes in Scala are represented with JVM primitives (same bytecode as Java's `int`, `double` etc.), see [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html).

Comment: Actually, Scala's `Tuple2` is specialized, so an `Int` in a `Tuple2` shouldn't be boxed.

Comment: I would rather look at the parallelization of the code. If you are able to split the work into smaller partitions/tasks. Please check if your input splits into handleable pieces of work. Otherwise you can try it out using the `.repartition(1200)` method. Where the number of partitions should be tuned an appropriate number based on the volume of data.

Comment: Thx a lot all of you for the kind answers and advice. I will look into all of them and update